# control one domain from other domain

Tags: dns, subdomain

i have been asked to make a marketing site.The concept provided is as follows-

There will be a parent site named www.game.com.It will have an admin.My client will create www.baseball.com,www.football.com,www.golf.com and so on.All these websites will have their own admin.

Now suppose a golf player named Jack comes to www.game.com admin and asks him to register himself.

My client is saying that www.game.com admin will be able to register that player under www.golf.com because he is a golf player and Jack will get a subdomain like www.golf.com/Jack

```
                                  www.game.com/admin
```

www.baseball.com/admin              www.football.com/admin              www.golf.com/admin

How is it possible ? how should i approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking at doing is called URL rewriting.  Check out this article for the basics of how it works.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

You will also find links to various methods for specific languages and platforms.

Comment: www.baseball.com,www.football.com,www.golf.com these will be created manually not from admin

Comment: You will be using the url rewriting to create a fake url for jack in this case.  For example you want jack to be able to go to www.golf.com/jack and see his player details.  You will use url rewriting to present the page www.golf.com/playerDetails.php?playername=jack as the page www.golf.com/jack.  Secondarily you will also probably want to point all your vanity urls to the same server.  Your app will live on www.game.com and all the vanity urls (www.golf.com, www.baseball.com, etc) will point to the same server and code that runs game.com.